# Updating a field subtract from a variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, records

what's the correct syntax in subtracting a field value from a variable value?

Example:

```
field1 = 100
variable1 = 10
```

I want to subtract variable1 from field1 using codeigniter's active records

my current code looks like this:

```
$this->db->set('volume', 'volume'-$r['quantity'], FALSE)
                    ->where('code',$r['ingredient_id'])
                    ->update('tbl_ingredients');
volume is the field
$r['quantity] is the variable
```

is this correct? because i get wrong results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->set('volume', 'volume-'.$r['quantity'], FALSE)
```

Comment: this actually worked. thanks man. why haven't i thought abuot concatenating volume and the variable. thanks again man. :)

Comment: sure. but stackoverflow says i can accep answer after a certain minutes. but i will man. thanks

Comment: Your original code (@Jetoox) was specifying 'volume' - $r['quantity'], or rather PHP was trying to subtract the numeric from your string 'volume'.  In safarovs solution, PHP sees a string 'volume-'.$r['quantity'] and so passes that to MySQL, which translates it to be field `volume` minus a numeric value == what you want :)